# How do I fix a squeaky/whiny ceiling fan?

Tags: repair, ceiling-fan

I have a four year old Monte Carlo ceiling fan, similar to this [now-discontinued model 5OBR52BSD-L](http://www.montecarlofans.com/18871/Ceiling-Fan-5OBR52BSD.html) in style.  It has a light that points up towards the ceiling and another towards the floor.  The fan is making a whiny, almost squeaky noise, on all 3 speed settings.

[image]

How do I fix this?  With some good ol' WD-40 and luck?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that it would depend on where the squeak is coming from.

If it;s inside the mechanism, or somewhere where parts of the fan are rubbing tegether then some WD-40 would probably fix it right up, but if the whole mounting is wobbling and causing the mount to rub against the junction box then you might try tightening the mounting hardware or shimmiing it out with something to make the mounting tighter.

Answer (score 2):

A whinny noise suggests to me that it's likely something in the movement of the motor or attached assembly.  Careful application of WD40 might be of some use if you can get it in past the blades, and closer to the motor itself.  If that worked, but only for a short time, I would probably look for a way to open it up a bit (careful to turn off power first, and not just at the wall switch) and clean and oil more deeply.

It's possible it's just dirty, but I would guess that it's a bit more likely some parts are starting to wear a bit.  A slightly heavier oil (like 3-in-1 or similar), ***might*** give you slightly longer relief than WD40 but it will be harder to get into the right places.